# Query all user defined types from Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I query all user defined data types from sql server like the way I do this for database object which are stored in sysobjects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 (and above) you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Types WHERE is_user_defined = 1
```

If you are on SQL Server 2000, you can use SysTypes. I think the query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM SysTypes WHERE xusertype > 256
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sys.types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx) view for this. When `user_type_id` and `system_type_id` are different, you have a user type.

As AakashM says, the `sys.types` view is only available from SQL Server 2005 and higher.

EDIT: A better way to determine whether a type is a user-defined type is to check the `is_user_defined` flag (see Tim C's answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are still on SQL Server 2000 (as your use of '`sysobjects`' suggests), look in `systypes`. If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later, as rwwilden says you should use `sys.types` (and move to using `sys.objects` rather than `sysobjects`!)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard query to get all the User defined databases alone. We can use

```
select * from sys.databases
```

But it shows all the Databases, I'm using Server management studio. So by default i have the following databases named : `'Master','tempdb','msdb','model'`

So i always use this following query to get the user defined databases.

```
select * from sys.databases where name not in('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
```

It works for fine. If you have extra databases by default, it will be the Following (resource,distribution,reportservice, reportservicetemp). Just use the names in that query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES has UDFs and Stored Procs.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES has tables and views.

Answer (score 0):

Actually system_type_id being different from user_type_id is NOT a good indication.  Note that this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Types 
WHERE (system_type_id <> user_type_id)
AND is_user_defined = 0.
```

Returns these:

- hierarchyid
- geometry
- geography
- sysname

So use `SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1` as was pointed out by Tim C and Ronald Wildenberg

Answer (score 0):

You can also find these in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.
personally I prefer to use that over the sys schema, as it's an ANSI standard that works over multiple types of databases.